# Isn't "text-overflow: ellipsis" valid CSS?

Tags: css, w3c-validation

This code triggers an error when run through the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator):

```
p{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I get:

```
Line     Code context      Error/Warning
2        p                 Parse Error [empty string]
```

Is it just a bug in the validator or am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [bug in the CSS validator](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=16250), it has been already reported. `text-overflow:ellipsis` is a valid rule, however the W3C CSS validator is unfortunately prone to errors (see [bug list](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/buglist.cgi?product=CSSValidator)).

However, note that the current working draft lists some `text-overflow` values as [feature at risk](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-ui-20120117/#atrisk):

> The Working Group has identified the following features as at risk of being removed from CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 3 when exiting CR. Implementors are urged to implement these features, if they wish to see these features remain in this specification. All other features are either defined in a normative reference (e.g. CSS 2.1 [CSS21] or Selectors [SELECT]) or are believed to have two or more implementations, and thus will not be dropped without returning to last call.
>
> - [...]
> - `text-overflow` property value: `<string>`
> - `text-overflow` property 2-value syntax and definition.

While this doesn't affect the `ellipsis` value, it could be the source of the bug in the validator:

> Parse Error [empty string]

#### References

- W3C: CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 3 (CSS3 UI):  (WD-20120117)

  - [Features at risk](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-ui-20120117/#atrisk)
  - [8.2. Overflow Ellipsis: the ‘text-overflow’ property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-ui-20120117/#text-overflow)

Comment: With regard to it being at risk...I read it that certain variations of `text-overflow` are at risk, not the whole thing. User agent support should justify keeping at least the basic ellipsis implementation.

Comment: @TimMedora: Yes, addressed this concern and made it more clear. Only some features property values are at risk, not the property itself. `ellipsis` isn't at risk, however, since the validator prints `[empty String]` as error, I suspect that those properties are creating the validator's behavior.

Comment: This error has been around for [a very long time](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator-css/2008Jul/0006.html). I last ran into it myself in 2010-ish, way before this recent LCWD. Frankly I don't know what they're doing with the validator. I hope they're rewriting it.

Answer (score 2):

It's valid based on [MDN's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow), which also links to the spec: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#text-overflow

Out of curiosity, I ran one of my own sites through the validator. I noted that it listed a few things that I would not consider errors, such as properly prefixed vendor extensions and data URIs.

Comment: Vendor extensions are not valid because they're not part of the standard. However, they are defined in the grammar so implementations can use them.