# Why styling of li does not work in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div like this shown below, and I am trying to set properties like *italic, font-style, font-size* to them which don't work properly.

---

```
<div id="cstopics" class="mytabclass">
    <p class="tabpanelfont">Data mining and data warehousing</p>
    <ul>
       <li>Data mining techniques</li>
       <li>Knowledge discovery</li>
       <li>Association rule mining</li>
       <li>Data warehousing architectures</li>
       <li>Multidimensional modelling and queries</li>
    </ul>
    <!--Few more ul elements -->
</div>
```

---

```
.mytabclass p{
    font-size: 16px;!important 

}

.mytabclass li {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

---

But nothing seems to work, can someone explain why ??

Comment: li is not a child element of div. You will probably need a separate class for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work -

```
.mytabclass p{
    font-size: 16px; /*You used !important after semicolon which is not the correct use of it and in this situation its not necessary*/
}

.mytabclass ul li {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

To replace bullet with dash do the following:

```
.mytabclass ul{
        list-style-type: none;
    }
.mytabclass ul li{
        font-size: 12px;
        font-style: italic;        
        background: url(pathToDashImage.jpg) no-repeat left top;
        padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to replace the bullet sign in <li> by a dash - sign ??

Comment: Actually I don't have an image. Can't I directly use it someway ??

Comment: @CSSS check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200249/html-list-style-type-dash

Answer (score 1):

```
4  mytabclass p    parser error ;!important }
```

`!imporant` has to be part of the value of the rule. Stating it after the `;` is a syntax error, which will often lead to the following rules being ignored. Apart from that your logic is fine.

```
.mytabclass p{
    font-size: !important 16px;
}

.mytabclass li {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

You can use [w3c css validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator) to prevent future errors. Keep in mind that the validator itself [has some bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757446/isnt-text-overflow-ellipsis-valid-css/11757563#11757563), but its syntax parser should be good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. This is weird. It worked for me when tested using [This Real-time HTML editor](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any mistake in your CSS. Problem is often somewhere else. Maybe another rule is overriding this. Try this and if nothing change problem is not in your css:

```
body div.mytabclass ul li {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```